# How to bind controls with models in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to bind controls on my `razor` view but getting error:

here is my `Order` model:

```
    public class OrderViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }


        public AreaCatalog Area { get; set; }

        [Display(Name="Sub Total")]
        public int SubTotal { get; set; }

        public int Discount { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Delivery Fee")]
        public int DeliveryFee { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Total Amount")]
        public int TotalAmount { get; set; }

        public List<ProductViewModel> Product { get; set; }

    }
```

that is included in ProductOrderViewModel as below:

```
    public class ProductOrderViewModel
    {
        public List<ProductViewModel> Products { get; set; }

        public List<OrderViewModel> Orders { get; set; }
    }
```

here is my controller code:

```
        public ActionResult Edit()
        {
            ResponseModel result = new ResponseModel();
            result = new Logic().GetProducts();
            //var model = new ProductOrderViewModel() { Products = result.Model, Orders = yy };
            var model = new ProductOrderViewModel() { Products = result.Model };
            if (result.Success)
                return View(model);

            return View();

        }
```

and here is my view code:

```
@model ProductOrderViewModel
@using Helpers
@using ViewModels;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.Orders.Area, new { @name = "area", @style = "width:295px; height:25px;margin-left:5px;" })
```

and Error is :

does not contain a definition for 'Area' and no extension method 'Area' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List

Please guide me through this problem

Comment: on what line is the error?

Comment: @Oluwafemi the line containing EnumDropDownListFor .

Comment: What is in `Orders` can you show the class?

Comment: It appears that Areas might be some sort of List that has not been initialized in your model class (via constructor), as it appears you are not setting that value in your Edit action. Please add sample code of your ProductOrderViewModel.

Comment: @Oluwafemi  I have edited my question please see it and guide me where to change

Comment: @ChrisBohatka I have edited my question please see it and guide me where to change

Comment: Your model on your view is a ProductOrderViewModel, though the class you have added is just an OrderViewModel. Is this correct?

Comment: `Area` is not a List that's why its breaking. It is expecting a type of `List<AreaCatalog>` and you not showing the correct class

Comment: @ChrisBohatka sorry i forgot to put that code...please see my question now

Comment: @Oluwafemi sorry i forgot to put that code...please see my question now

Comment: On a separate note, the OrderViewModel has a list of ProductViewModel, and ProductOrderViewModel has it's own list of ProductViewModel, which is also in OrderViewModel.

Comment: who is the down voter...you have to specify your problem here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as error says: `does not contain a definition for 'Area' and no extension method 'Area' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`

`Area` is property of your `OrderViewModel`, but not `List<OrderViewModel>`.

and you are actually trying to do something like:

```
//Assume:
List<OrderViewModel> myList = new List<OrderViewModel>();
```

and you are trying to draw `EnumDropDownlistFor` `myList.Area`. Which is not EVER possible. because `Area` is not a property of `Generic List`

Comment: but in that way getting Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'Cygnus.Global.ViewModels.OrderViewModel' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Cygnus.Global.ViewModels.OrderViewModel>' D:\CygnusDev\GDR\OST\OST\Cygnus.Website.Base\Controllers\OrderController.cs

Comment: Downvoter, you are welcome to comment here. Please point out the problem?